# HTTP Get request single object Ionic 2

Tags: arrays, json, angular, object, typescript

I am using an API to pull data which is then printed onto the page, I have successfully got this to work for a json response of more than 1 object, as this parses though a "matches" hierarchy. If i do this for one object I cannot seem to print it out.

The Json i have working and can print out already is

[image]

and code that works

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of api" [navPush] = "detailsPage" detail-push>
            <div class="thumb">
                <img src="{{item.smallImageUrls}}">
            </div>
            <div class="text">
                <div class="title">
                    <h1>{{item.recipeName}}</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="rating">
                    <rating [(ngModel)]="item.rating"></rating>
                </div>
                <div class="time">
                    <p>{{item.totalTimeInSeconds | HoursMinutesSeconds}} minutes</p>
                </div>
                <div class="ingredients">
                    <p>{{item.ingredients.length}} Ingredients</p>
                </div>

                <div class="course">
                    <p>{{item.attributes.course}} </p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Typescript

```
    this.http.get('http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=397aed16&_app_key=69e2565adcec7a6609b18bef31261e62')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
        // and save the data for later reference
        console.log(data);
        this.listing = data.matches;
        resolve(this.listing);
      });
```

Json is and stuck on

[image: Json data]

my request is

```
this.http.get('mylink.co.uk')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.details = data;
    resolve(this.details);
  });
```

and angular to be `{{attribution}}`

If someone could point out where I'm going wrong that would be great

Comment: So you are telling you want to print  this.details.attribution . Dosent this work in the template?

Comment: @RahulSingh Yes, I want to print out any of them items, but it just leaves me with an empty html element

Comment: Can you try like this this.details[0].attribution

Comment: @RahulSingh That threw up an error, i have updated my question with code that currently works and prints out the objects already to make it more clearer what I am aiming for.

Comment: So u got a solution right ? Great

Answer (score 0):

You should be using **any[]** to typecast to an array of data

```
this.http.get('mylink.co.uk')
  .map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.details = data;
    resolve(this.details);
  });
```

**Update 1:**

You should be using an interface and create the relevant properties and bind them to the result that is returned by the API interface should be

```
export interface Reciepe {

    criteria: Criteria;
    matches: Matches;
    faceCounts: any;
    totalMatchCount: number;
    attribution: Attributes;
}

export interface Criteria {

    q: any;
    allowedIngredient: any;
    excludedIngredient: any;
}

export interface Matches {
    imageUrlsBySize: ImageUrlsBySize;
    sourceDisplayName: string;
    ingredients: string[];
    smallImageUrls: string[];
    recipeName: string;
    totalTimeInSeconds: number;
    attributes: Attributes;
    flavors: any;
    rating: number;
}

export interface Attribution {
    html: string;
    url: string;
    text: string;
    logo: string;

}
export interface ImageUrlsBySize {

    90: string;

}
export interface Attributes {
    course: string[];
}
```

Your typescript code should be modified as

```
this.http.get('mylink.co.uk')
  .map((response: Response) => <Reciepe>response.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.details = data;
    resolve(this.details);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but It hasn't seemed to make any difference?

Comment: do you have array inside an array. U want to **print** the elements **or** **bind** it to you data object?

Comment: I have updated my question with code that currently works and prints out the objects already to make it more clearer what I am aiming for. What already works is a list of them thats goes through the **object -> matches and then each item** this one just goes through **object** which is where im stuck

Comment: are you available in team viewer?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example i thing it's will solved your question , i followed and i solved my problem .

See:

https://angular.io/guide/http

https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml

**models.ts:**

```
export interface Location {
  id?: string;
  name?: string;
  author?: { 
    id?: string, 
    name?: string, 
    followerCount?: string
  }
}
```

**mock-locations.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { Location } from '@core/models';

@Injectable()
export class MockLocationsService  {

  private readonly URL = 'assets/data/locations.json';

  constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  public list(): Observable<Location[]>   {
    return this.httpClient.get<Location[]>(this.URL);
  }

}
```

**my.page.ts:**

```
  import { Location } from '@core/models';
    
    ...
    
    export class MyPage implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    
      public items: Array<Location> = [];
      private itemsSubscription: Subscription;
    
      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                  public navParams: NavParams,
                  private locationsService: MockLocationsService,
                  private logger: LoggerService) {
    
      }
      ...
    
      public ngOnInit() {
    
        this.itemsSubscription = this.locationsService.list().subscribe(data => {
          this.items = data;
        });
      }
    
      ...
    
      public ngOnDestroy() {
        this.itemsSubscription.unsubscribe();
      }
    
    }
```

Reference :  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-map-api-objects-in-ionic-in-a-good-way/140249/2